# In Spring Boot, how to catch an error and do something with it before displaying error.html?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, error-handling

I am using Spring Boot 3 with Java 8, and have an error.html that automatically gets shown when an exception anywhere in the code bubbles all the way up to the top.

Is there a bean method I should configure to do something with the exception( e.g. send an email out for notification) before finally showing the error.html?

Thanks
IS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@ExceptionHandler` if you want to handle Exceptions thrown from a specific controller or create a global exception handler class and annotate it with `@ControllerAdvice`.

See: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc